# Calculate the correlation between two Space-Time Series

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, spatial, spatio-temporal

What method would be employed to calculate the correlation between two space-time series?

For example, dataset 1 = a set of space-time points relating to cases of disease 1 and dataset 2 = a set of space-time points relating to cases of disease 2.

How can the correlation between theses two spatio-temporal series be assessed to see if the spread of disease 2 is related to disease 1?

I can find measures for assessing the interaction of a single series as well as temporal correlation and spatial correlation separately but nothing when the two are intertwined.